# Spatial join arcgis pro

Tags: python, pycharm, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I got this shape files Highway1,Highway2,Highway3 etc... The attribute tables are the same, they contain info about latitude, longitude , direction, shape_length and speed_allowed.

I want to make a script in python that would allow me to make a spatial join between every shape file that intersect other . For example if Highway1 intersect Highway2 , Highway12 and Highway22 i want 3 spatial join, every join should contain all the data from Highway 1 and where intersect the other highway, to have that info merged and where it does not intersect to have null values for the second highway.

Please help me write a script in order to automatically find if highway1 intersect other highway and if it does to make that kind of spatial join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find what you need in the [ESRI Documentation](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/analysis_tools/intersect_analysis_.htm) and in the [ArcPy Documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/importing-arcpy.htm). Try their code samples, adapt it to your needs and then you are able to ask more specifically.

Here's an example of [ESRI's Intersect Docs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm#C_GUID-55EE559D-C772-4180-989E-FB3018FA13D6):

```
#Name: VegRoadIntersect.py
# Purpose: Determine the type of vegetation within 100 meters of all stream crossings

# Import system modules
import arcpy
 
# Set the workspace (to avoid having to type in the full path to the data every time)
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/data/data.gdb"    
    
# Process: Find all stream crossings (points)
inFeatures = ["roads", "streams"]
intersectOutput = "stream_crossings"
clusterTolerance = 1.5    
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(inFeatures, intersectOutput, "", clusterTolerance, "point")
 
# Process: Buffer all stream crossings by 100 meters
bufferOutput = "stream_crossings_100m"
bufferDist = "100 meters"
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(intersectOutput, bufferOutput, bufferDist)

# Process: Clip the vegetation feature class to stream_crossing_100m
clipInput = "vegetation"
clipOutput = "veg_within_100m_of_crossings"
arcpy.Clip_analysis(clipInput, bufferOutput, clipOutput)

# Process: Summarize how much (area) of each type of vegetation is found
# within 100 meter of the stream crossings
statsOutput = "veg_within_100m_of_crossings_stats"
statsFields = [["shape_area", "sum"]]
caseField = "veg_type"
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(clipOutput, statsOutput, statsFields, caseField)
```